# Get navigation props in an independent component React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

My `app.js` file looks like this

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (
        <Root style={{
            flex: 1
        }}>
            <FcmHandler/>
        </Root>
    )
 }

}
```

The `Root` component is where the entire app resides along with all the functionality, the `FcmHandler` is where I handle functionality related to notifications etc. Within the `FcmHandler` I have a method that gets a callback when a notification is clicked, inside this callback I need to navigate to a specific screen in the app based on the notification click.

The problem is using the current code above the `FcmHandler` component never even gets initialized.

If I try something like this

```js
 export default class App extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (
        <View style={{
            flex: 1
        }}>
            <Root/>
            <FcmHandler/>
        </View>
    )
 }
}
```

the `FcmHandler` component gets called but I do not have any access to navigation props which reside inside the `<Root/>` component.

The `<Root/>` component consists of the following

```js
const ArticleStack = StackNavigator(
    {
        ...
    }
);


const SettingsStack = StackNavigator({
    ...
});


export const Root = StackNavigator({
    Articles: {
        screen: ArticleStack
    },
    Settings: {
        screen: SettingsStack

    },
}, {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none'
});
```

The basic goal I am trying to achieve is, when a notification is click, irrespective of which screen the app is currently on I should be able to navigate to a particular screen. I do not want to write the navigation code in every screen component that I have, that seems redundant.

Comment: Are you using `redux-navigation` by any chance? I might have a solution for that.

Comment: I am not but If you could let me know the solution anyway it might help me reach my goal or possibly help anyone else who stumbles upon this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow [this official guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html) to create your navigation service. Then use the navigation service in `FcmHandler` instead of `navigation` prop. This way there is no need to put `FcmHandler` as a child of the navigator.

If you are using redux or mobx, it's better to move your navigation state to the store for easier access. For redux, there is an [official integration guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/redux-integration.html). For mobx, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767879/how-to-navigate-in-mobx-store-using-react-navigation/49802965#49802965).

Answer (score 1):

For `react-navigation` users, a really cool way is to create your own **Navigation Service**

You can initialize your **Navigation Service** module, during the time initializing your navigation store as mentioned in their [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/redux-integration.html)

```js
 <AppNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
    dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
    state: this.props.nav,
    addListener,
  })} />
 // Just add another line to config the navigator object
  NavigationService.configNavigator(dispatch) <== This is the important part
```

**NavigationService.js**

```js
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'

      let config = {}

      const configNavigator = nav => {
        config.navigator = nav
      }

      const reset = (routeName, params) => {
        let action = NavigationActions.reset({
          index: 0,
          key: null,
          actions: [
            NavigationActions.navigate({
              type: 'Navigation/NAVIGATE',
              routeName,
              params,
            }),
          ],
        })
        config.navigator(action)
      }

      const navigate = (routeName, params) => {
        let action = NavigationActions.navigate({
          type: 'Navigation/NAVIGATE',
          routeName,
          params,
        })
        config.navigator(action)
      }

      const navigateDeep = actions => {
        let action = actions.reduceRight(
          (prevAction, action) =>
            NavigationActions.navigate({
              type: 'Navigation/NAVIGATE',
              routeName: action.routeName,
              params: action.params,
              action: prevAction,
            }),
          undefined
        )
        config.navigator(action)
      }

      const goBack = () => {
        if (config.navigator) {
          let action = NavigationActions.back({})
          config.navigator(action)
        }
      }

      export default {
        configNavigator,
        navigateDeep,
        navigate,
        reset,
        goBack,
      }
```

**Explanation** :

The `config` initializes the `navigator's dispatch` object whenever your `redux-navigation` gets initialzed, therefore you can `dispatch any navigation action`, **wrt** the method's present in the *Service Component*.

**Use**

```js
NavigationServices.navigate('ScreenName')
```

**Update:**
React Navigation now provides a `HOC wrapper` [`withNavigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/with-navigation), that passes the navigation prop into a wrapped component.

> It's useful when you cannot pass the navigation prop into the component directly, or don't want to pass it in case of a deeply nested child.

Usage is well mentioned in their [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/with-navigation).

Comment: While using this solution lets say I pass in some parameters to ScreenName route. How do I access them?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research, the easiest way I found was to follow their [official documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/):

1. I created a `RootNavigation.js` file in the `./misc` folder;

```js
import * as React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();
export function navigate(name, params) {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}
```

2. I imported it into App.js and created a reference to it in the return function:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { navigationRef } from './misc/rootNavigation'; <- navigationRef is imported

…

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}> <— reference to navigationRef
        <Stack.Navigator>
…
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Screen"
            component={Screen}
            options={{
              title: “Hello”,
              headerLeft: () => <ScreenButton/>
          }} />

        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App
```

3. I called it inside the `ScreenButton` component

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
…
import * as RootNavigation from '../misc/rootNavigation'; <—- imported

class RoomButton extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={
                () => {RootNavigation.navigate( 'RoomSelectorScreen' ) <—- called here
            …
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
}
```